# What can be a good modelisation for an open wire?

Tags: cables, modeling

How to modelise an open wire for a simulation purpose?
I think that it is more complicated than it sounds.

Comment: It depends on what frequencies are present on the wire, how long it is, and what type of wire it is (coax, bare wire, etc.) It would help if you explained these, what this wire is connected to, and what the simulation is intended to cover.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on length and frequency. For instance, a coax cable of 25 cm length fed with 300 MHz (wavelength 1 metre) will look like a short circuit to ground. It's called an impedance transformer: -

[image]

The relationship between the characteristic impedance, Z0, input impedance, Zin and load impedance, ZL is: -

[image]

If you just used a wire it would radiate and look like a few tens of ohms. It can be quite complex when the wavelength of the signal approaches that of the wire/cable length.

[Here's](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/alternating-current/chpt-14/impedance-transformation/) a good source for learning. It deals with quarter, half and 3/4 wave transformers and is pictorially very good.

Answer (score 1):

It strongly depends on how you want to simulate.

If you are simulating using SPICE - like tool, the program will either ignore the open wire or ask you to remove the open connection. However, like "rdtsc" pointed out some SPICE programs do have a model for transmission lines and possibly other useful features.

If you are performing electro-magnetic, electro-static and other simulations in a FEM program like FEMM or Comsol the modeling will be geometric and you can model the wire as a cylinder or a rectangle (3D-2D). However be careful when modeling the edges, as a 90 degree angle might give you very high electrostatic field strength while a small radius might reduce it with an order of magnitude. The surroundings like distance to other objects and ground is then also important in order to get a good model of reality.

If you want to make an analytic model of the wire it’s all about what frequencies you are working with. If the frequencies are high (RF) you might have reflections in the wire as well as other HF phenomena, see “Andy aka”s answer.

Comment: Many SPICE simulators have a "Transmission Line" primitive.